# How do I initialize a variable in an if else program that combines three choices?

Tags: java

I'm writing a party planner program for a question for class.

I can't initialize my three choices of entertainment, decorations, and food.

Eclipse tells me that I should set all these values to 0. I have to stick to these if else statements because that's what we have learned so far.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PartyPlanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        
        int entertainment;
        int decorations;
        int food;
        

        int budget = entertainment + decorations + food;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("For your choices, please type"
                + " in what is contained in the brackets."
                + " We will do the calculations for you.");
        System.out.println("Choose entertainment:"
                + " [band] for $400 or " + "[DJ] for $150");
        String choice1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        if (choice1 == "DJ") 
        {
            entertainment = 400;
        }
        
        else if (choice1 == "band")
        {
            entertainment = 150;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Where would you like to buy "
                + "decorations? [school] for $100 or [your own] for $250 ?");
        String choice2 = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        if (choice2 == "school")
        {
            decorations = 100;
        }
        
        else if (choice2 == "your own")
        {
            decorations = 250;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Would you like to purchase"
                + " [pizza] for $200 or [sub sandwiches]"
                + " for $250 or [appetizers] for $150?");
        String choice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        if (choice3 == "pizza") 
        {
            food = 200;
        }
        
        else if (choice3 == "sub sandwiches")
        {
            food = 250;
        }
        
        else if (choice3 == "appetizers") 
        {
            food = 150;
        }

        
        System.out.println("You have chosen: " + choice1 +
        " and " + choice2 + " and " + choice3);
        System.out.println("The total cost of this party"
                + " comes out to:" + budget);
        
    }

}
```

The problem is

**The local variable entertainment, decorations, and food may have not been initalized.**

Comment: First, initialize your variables with 0, like 'int decorations = 0;'. Second, compare strings with equals(), not '==', such as "appetizers".equals(choice3).

Comment: thanks! it was actually choice3.equals("appetizers") that helped.

Answer (score 3):

First , you have to make the sum at the end of the code because at first the variables are not initialized yet , and secondly you can assign a value of zero if no choice have been made , like this :

```
public class PartyPlanner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    
    int entertainment;
    int decorations;
    int food;
         
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("For your choices, please type"
            + " in what is contained in the brackets."
            + " We will do the calculations for you.");
    System.out.println("Choose entertainment:"
            + " [band] for $400 or " + "[DJ] for $150");
    String choice1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    if (choice1 == "DJ") 
    {
        entertainment = 400;
    }
    
    else if (choice1 == "band")
    {
        entertainment = 150;
    }
    else { entertainment = 0; }
    
    System.out.println("Where would you like to buy "
            + "decorations? [school] for $100 or [your own] for $250 ?");
    String choice2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    if (choice2 == "school")
    {
        decorations = 100;
    }
    
    else if (choice2 == "your own")
    {
        decorations = 250;
    }
    else { decorations = 0; }
    
    System.out.println("Would you like to purchase"
            + " [pizza] for $200 or [sub sandwiches]"
            + " for $250 or [appetizers] for $150?");
    String choice3 = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    if (choice3 == "pizza") 
    {
        food = 200;
    }
    
    else if (choice3 == "sub sandwiches")
    {
        food = 250;
    }
    
    else if (choice3 == "appetizers") 
    {
        food = 150;
    }
    else { food = 0 ; }

    int budget = entertainment + decorations + food;

    
    System.out.println("You have chosen: " + choice1 +
    " and " + choice2 + " and " + choice3);
    System.out.println("The total cost of this party"
            + " comes out to:" + budget);
    
}

}
```